# One Jewish Practice

Tags: mitzvah, non-religious

For someone who is Jewish, yet an atheist, what is one practice that is doable that they could keep?

With suggestions for one doable Jewish practice, prayer, etc; please include guidelines of how to keep it.

By doable, this means a mitzvah other than shmiras shabbos(since he/she is just starting out and may not be particularly ready for it).

**EDIT** I am happy that my question was not only allowed to stand, but also reopened.

In moving some of my earlier editing remarks to meta, the overriding motivation for asking my question is a bit obscured. So please allow me to restate or perhaps emphasize it for anyone subsequently looking at this question. I will take the liberty to use a statement by ezra and a major principle in a link by Yaacov Deane both below.

"But one of the most important things you can do (in my opinion) is be proud of being Jewish and be supportive of religious Jews. There are a lot of haters out there. Stand up. Be proud."

And the significance and importance of Ahavas Yisrael.

Again I express my appreciation for the existence of this site. I feel I have uniquely benefitted.

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya! Thank you for your question and we hope you take a look at what Mi Yodeya has to offer.

Comment: **Let's take the discussion about this post's fitness for our model and how to improve it over to here: https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4805/can-we-improve-the-one-jewish-practice-question-post .**

Comment: @user18223 I was thinking more about your situation, and what it means to be a very basic level of religious. This led me to a new idea for you: Toss around the thought of keeping a kosher kitchen. There's no need to rush, for it can be done at any time. But a kosher kitchen is one subtle mark that separates the "committed" Jews from the "ambivalent" Jews. It gives the Jews who keep it a link to their tradition that, while not invasive, leaves its impression. Just a thought for the future.... Much bracha to you, whatever you do

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try putting on Teffilin daily, and reciting the Shema daily.

And if you don’t have a pair of teffilin, just the Shema. But your local Lubavitch center will gladly loan you a pair.

Comment: Not in shabbat!

Comment: The sex of the OP is undetermined. Tefillin are only for males. What if they are a woman?

Comment: The word is "Lubavitch". And they're called "Chabad houses".

Comment: @ezra Not all of them! In fact, I think there is a move today toward calling them "Chabad centers." And of course there is a "Lubavitch House"

Comment: @SAH Ok but it's definitely not Labuvitch

Comment: @yaacov if tefillin help a woman get to keeping kosher and Shabbat, it's worth it.

Answer (score 18):

I think you should begin the practice of learning something Jewish every day.

This mitzvah is, in my mind, both necessary and sufficient for a Jewish life. Why? Because it keeps your pintele yid not only burning, but uncovered and unforgotten-- allowing it to light up the rest of your life, and the world.  Also, this mitzvah uniquely enables the performance of all other mitzvot, should you choose to do more.

Learning, specifically Torah learning, is [what Jews do](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/3852166/jewish/What-Do-Jews-Do.htm). Learning is and always has been at the center of gravity of Jewish life.

The Talmud puts an emphasis on learning every day at a fixed time. According to the Talmud, that is the [subject](http://dafyomi.co.il/shabbos/points/sh-ps-031.htm) of one of the Creator's first questions to every Jew after death.

It is no accident that our beautiful, untrammeled tradition is endlessly full of wise and serious and gratifying things to learn--for example, the Talmud itself. [Herman Wouk](https://openlibrary.org/works/OL729145W/This_is_my_God) writes in his essay "Why Daf Yomi?":

> [...] Because by now the Talmud is in my bones. Its elegant and arcane
>   ethical algebra, its soaked-in quintessential Jewishness, its fun, its
>   difficulty, its accumulative virtue (“I learned a ‘blatt’ [a two-sided
>   page] today, I’ve learned 40 ‘blatt’ this year”) all balance against
>   the cost in time and the so-called “remoteness from reality.” Is
>   ‘Lear’ closer to reality? I think they are about as close (‘l’havdil,’
>   as my rabbi would interject) in different ways, and that the Talmud is
>   holy besides.
>
> Anyway, I love it. That’s reason enough.

---Preferably at the same time every day. Preferably beginning with [this](https://www.chabad.org/library/howto/trainer_cdo/aid/1771250/jewish/Torah-Blessings-Trainer.htm#!31/1239/v1) blessing, or as you see fit. Every day, learn one small piece of the [wisdom](http://rabbisacks.org/tenpaths/educators/study/) your forefathers discovered. You won't regret it. Hatzlacha raba.

Comment: It's true; learning gemara can do wonders.

Comment: I really appreciate this answer and have read it over many times. Of course, I am, thanks to you, going through the Rabbi Sacks pieces. If I may ask, do you have a math background? I've rarely seen "necessary and sufficient" outside of that context. Maybe in the future I might ask you for further advice. Meantime, best personal regards,

Comment: @user18223 I'm really grateful for your comment and particularly glad I was able to help you. I wish I had a math background, but I don't. "Necessary and sufficient" is something that one hears, I guess :) I wish you much success in your search for a link to our beautiful tradition. Meanwhile, reach out anytime -- I'm on Mi.Yodeya constantly.

Comment: I wanted to let you know that I've taken your advice and started Mishnah Yomit. Actually last week I posted a question stating my intention and acknowledging you as motivating it. In it I linked several possible sites and asked for any additional ones I might consider. Needless to say, while I did get an up vote, I immediately got a downvote and a close vote. So I deleted my question - don't want to go through the harangue again. I did find a shiur I like; and I wanted to thank you. Best regards,

Comment: @user18223 Kol hakavod! I am really happy you started learning. May your learning bring you much happiness and blessing for many long years!

Comment: @user18223 I really hope you don't give up on Mi.Yodeya. I had the same experience when I started, and it was very discouraging. I don't know what changed - whether I eventually learned to hit the right note with my questions, or whether people were less inclined to look at my questions skeptically because I had spent more time on the site. (I think, in any case, it is very unfortunate that some members hold site standards such as question scope at higher value than the feelings and potential future Jewish education of a fellow Jew and/or human being, and, when I dare, I still stick my neck+

Comment: @user18223 out to fight this.) That said, paying my dues here was ultimately very worthwhile. I therefore really hope you'll consider coming back here and continuing to ask questions you feel are important.

Answer (score 13):

You can learn the blessing of Shehakol and recite it before you take a drink. Once you learn it (and that can take time), it takes about two seconds to say. You can learn the words [here](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/278547/jewish/Shehakol-The-Blessing-on-All-Other-Foods.htm).

Shehakol, like all blessings, is an expression of gratitude to God for giving us the good things in life. Studies have shown that regularly expressing gratitude and appreciation for the simple things in life makes one happier and healthier (see for example [here](https://www.psychologytoday.com/us/blog/what-mentally-strong-people-dont-do/201504/7-scientifically-proven-benefits-gratitude)). Getting into the habit of regularly expressing appreciation for drinks may help you spiritually, physically, and emotionally.

I commend you on your interest on taking on a practice. We believe that every single mitzvah counts, and that every single mitzvah has a positive effect on the doer and the whole world.

Comment: Not just drinks, but before the first bite at every meal

Comment: @DoubleAA Let's start small. We can add on when we're ready.

Comment: @Double AA "shehakol" before every meal is a great idea but presents problems due to Kashrut

Comment: @joshk and you assume all drinks are kosher?

Answer (score 7):

Lighting candles on Friday night.  Stop everything.  Turn off electronics.  If you live with others and they're willing, bring them over to join you.  Light two candles* and hold still for a few moments.  Just focus on the flame and the spirit.  If possible, say the prayer while lighting them, but don't worry if lighting is all you do for now (or ever).

- I recommend buying candles made for Shabbat because they will be the right size.  You don't want them to burn for too long or you will be tempted to blow them out for fire safety reasons.  Spring for a set of candlesticks too.  You can get nice ones at a thrift store or garage sale for probably $5US.

Comment: But make sure to light them *before* sunset.

Comment: Hi Cyn - I'll tell you a "funny" story. I had considered buying Shabbos candles as you suggest. I checked them out at amzn, but held off. Shortly thereafter, I decided to buy them, and when I was about to enter my order, I got a message that I had already purchased them! Mi Yodeya? Best regards,

Comment: This answer has a particular merit unlike all others: there's ample record of descendants of Marranos (Spanish Anusim) keeping this one practice *to this day*, even when all memory of *why* has been lost. This one custom has made it possible to recognise people as descendants of Jews, though the Edict of Expulsion happened over 500 years ago.

Answer (score 6):

Make Friday night dinner as special as possible, and at any rate your best meal of the week. Just pulling out the top-shelf booze and grilling some steaks is a (BIG) step in the right direction. If you feel comfortable lighting candles and saying a bracha as part of that, all the better.  It's once a week, it's fun, and it doesn't require too much sacrifice, whaddya say?

(On a personal note this is actually how I ended up becoming religious)

Comment: You're already going to eat; why not make it shabbat? Good suggestion.

Comment: Also it has the advantage of tricking your yetzer hara. When you go from no Jewish practice to some, it will do everything it can to stop you. But how will your yetzer hara object to a nice dinner and good booze? It can't :)

Answer (score 6):

First of all, I highly recommend putting on tefillin and reciting the Shema, as mentioned in [the answer from Dr. Shmuel](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/96715/11486). Just make sure not to don tefillin on Shabbat or the holidays.

As far as blessings are concerned, maybe you could learn some of the blessings in the siddur over different kinds of food and recite them (for instance, the blessing of "borei p'ri ha'eitz" before eating an apple).

([Here](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/90551/jewish/Texts-of-Blessings-Before-Eating.htm) is a great resource for learning the text of the blessings.)

I'd also encourage you to give [tzedakah](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/814118/jewish/Tzedakah-Charity.htm) in some way.

But one of the most important things you can do (in my opinion) is be proud of being Jewish and be supportive of religious Jews. There are a lot of haters out there. Stand up. Be proud.

Good luck and all the best to you my friend.

Comment: Your penultimate remark is precisely why I came here - stand up and be proud. The pintele yid I mentioned is an internal drive. Yet I wanted some external manifestation; to show the flag.

Comment: @user18223 For that, the really brave might consider a mezuzah and/or a kippah and/or a hat ;)

Answer (score 6):

From personal experience, I can recommend taking on *shemiras halashon*, i.e. no negative speech about anyone, even if it's true, even if they're a mean and nasty person and they *frickin' well deserve it*!

*(Notable exception: if you need to relate negative information in order to save someone else from being damaged, you **must** do so. There's a lot of detail to this point, but that's the basic rule.)*

Before I became religious, this was the first mitzva I took on. You don't have to believe in God to appreciate the value in not bad-mouthing people.

Answer (score 5):

Welcome to Mi Yodeya and thank you for persisting with your excellent question.

Especially in consideration of recent current events, as you have already commented about concerning the sad and terrible synagogue shooting in Pittsburgh, it is highly admirable and praiseworthy that you come forward with your question now.

It demonstrates a desire to show *unity with **your people***, even though philosophically you may not agree with them about everything. And also that ***we all*** (not just *your own people*) must get along with each other in harmony. That appears to be the underlying foundation of the ***one practice*** that you seek.

As a self-professed *atheist*, the content of your question, that you seek suggestions of what would be doable/achievable by you personally, also indicates your character. That you try to be realistic about your nature and apply a rigorous, intellectually honest, measure to your own life.

With that in mind, if you are seeking one, single practice, what is called in traditional Jewish terminology a single mitzvah/commandment that you could keep, it seems appropriate and logical to seek something that is comprehensive and all inclusive in its scope.

It should also be something that you can relate to intellectually, emotionally and spiritually. Ideally, it should be something which you can study about in depth over time and reflect upon again and again, which will lead you to positive growth as a human being for the rest of your life. This is the concept of *good* in Judaism, that which leads to an increase, profusion and diversification of life.

With all this in mind, a famous story found in the Talmud, [tractate Shabbat 31a](https://www.sefaria.org/Shabbat.31a?lang=en), concerning two of traditional Judaism's most famous Sages, Hillel the Elder and Shammai comes to mind. An individual with essentially no knowledge of Jewish practice and teaching came before Hillel seeking his help and advice to find this same type of thing. He was seeking *the whole of Torah*, a single mitzvah so to speak. And Hillel replied to him:

> That which is hateful to you do not do to another; that is the entire Torah, and the rest is its interpretation. Go study.

As is explained by one of our later Sages, Rabbi Shneur Zalman of Liady, in his book, [Likkutei Amarim Tanya, chapter 32](https://www.chabad.org/library/tanya/tanya_cdo/aid/7911/jewish/Chapter-32.htm), This single mitzvah, called *Ahavat Re'im* (Love of neighbors) which is based upon the expression from our Torah ([VaYikra 19:18](https://www.sefaria.org/Leviticus.19.18?lang=en&with=all&lang2=en)), *Ve'Ahavta le'Rei'acha Kamocha* which means:

> Love your fellow as yourself.

demonstrates that, in reality, we are all *brothers* (as in brotherhood, not sexual characteristic) with a single, common *Father*. (It is worth noting that in Hebrew, *father* can also mean *source*.)

The beginnings of the details of what this particular mitzvah practice entails are discussed by Rabbi Schneur Zalman in that chapter. It is worthwhile to read it carefully, reflect upon it and try to incorporate its performance into your life.

Further intellectual underpinnings about this mitzvah and its importance are also found at the following link discussing *[Loving a Fellow Jew and Loving G-d](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/2312300/jewish/Chapter-2-Ahavas-Yisrael-and-Ahavas-HaShem-Loving-a-Fellow-Jew-and-Loving-G-d.htm)*.

May you be blessed with success in pursuit of your goal here. And I am sure, like myself, we are all looking forward to your continued positive contributions to our community.

Comment: Thank you for the most heart-warming, uplifting, encouraging personal message. It is far beyond what would otherwise be called an answer. I am deeply touched. With deepest personal regards,

Comment: While loving others is certainly a good thing to do within Judaism, is it a distinctly Jewish practice?

Comment: @Alex The mitzvah is 'Ahavat Rei'im', not loving 'others' which would be 'Ahavat Acherim'. What it means to the Jewish people is as it is taught within the Torah. If you don't understand what that means precisely, you might want to read through the links in this answer for starters. That would give you a good beginning to comprehending the unique Jewish teaching about this mitzvah.

Comment: @YaacovDeane I'm not talking about the parameters of the mitzvah. I'm saying that loving someone is not really a manifestation of Judaism, even if it happens to be a fulfillment of a commandment. It is certainly not an *external* manifestation, i.e. something that is noticeably Jewish.

Comment: @Alex Then your comment is not about the answer. It's about the subject of 'love' and whether that concept, as taught and understood according to the Torah, is a 'manifestation of Judaism'. (Not exactly sure what you mean by that.)

Comment: But traditional Torah teaching concerning the recital of Shema, something which is a clear Jewish manifestation, both internally and externally, tells us that one of the intentions we are to have upon saying the word "Echod" (אחד), as in 'G-d is one', at the end of the 1st line, means among other things, "Love/Ahava" (אהבה). 'Echod' and 'Ahava' share a common gematria of 13, like in G-d's 13 attributes of mercy which we recite all day on Yom Kippur, at every Festival and after Viduy on Monday and Thursday.

Comment: My comment is about the answer. If I was looking for a practice to make me feel Jewish, I would not be looking for something like love, which is something that I would be doing regardless of my religion. And if I was looking for something to *display* my Judaism, I certainly wouldn't be looking for something like love, because that is not recognizably Jewish. Indeed, this is part of the reason why the question probably should have remained closed — the parameters are not defined enough.